# Bubbles in pressure waves

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bubbles

I found an article in which they say this, at the end they say that there is a net flux of gas into the bubble, but I don't understand why, since there is a dilatational phase (in which the bubbles grow) but also a compressional phase (in which the bubbles size decreases), considering me there is no flux in total then? Where am I wrong?

https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1535006

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to the article?

Comment: @AlexTrounev just added it.

Comment: Thank you, it can be read also here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260899765_Earthquake-Volcano_Interactions

Answer (score 0):

The cited fragment is taken from the popular article [1], where reference is made to three other articles [2-4], 
and there is also no detailed explanation of the dynamics of bubbles in magma in seismic waves.
But we can indicate one article [5], where this problem is studied.

1. David P. Hill, Fred Pollitz, and Christopher Newhall, EARTHQUAKE–VOLCANO INTERACTIONS, PHYSICS TODAY    41, NOV. 2002
2. Linde, A., Sacks, I., Johnston, M. et al. Increased pressure from rising bubbles as a mechanism for remotely triggered seismicity. Nature 371, 408–410 (1994). https://doi.org/10.1038/371408a0
3. Sahagian, D. L. & Proussevitch, A. A., Bubbles in volcanic systems, Nature 359, 485 (1992).
4. Sahagian, D. L. Nature 361, 308 (1993).
5. A. A. Proussevitch and D. L. Sahagian, Dynamics and energetics of bubble growth in magmas: Analytical formulation and numerical modeling
   JOURNAL OF GEOPHYSICAL RESEARCH, VOL. 103, NO. B8, PAGES 18,223-18,251, AUGUST 10, 1998 https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/98JB00906